# Inactive part of the screen on fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, click, fullscreen

I'm trying to put a picture on fullscreen with buttons on to do actions.

Here is a screenshot of my result:

[image: Screenshot]

My problem is that the buttons on the first line (the highest) are not touchable.
It seems to have no action on the top layout.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)showActionsForGlobalFullScreen:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {  
        //LEFT
        UIImage* cancelImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"];
        CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(3, 3, cancelImage.size.width, cancelImage.size.height);
        UIButton *cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
        
        UIImage* flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag.png"];
        CGRect frameimg2 = CGRectMake(3, 40, flagImage.size.width, flagImage.size.height);
        UIButton *flagButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg2];
        
        [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closeFullView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
        [cancelButton setBackgroundImage:cancelImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
        [flagButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayFlag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
        [flagButton setBackgroundImage:flagImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
        //RIGHT
        UIImage *exitFullScreenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"exitFullScreen.png"];
        CGRect frameimg3 = CGRectMake(fullScreenViewFromVC.frame.size.width - 25 , 3, exitFullScreenImage.size.width, exitFullScreenImage.size.height);
        UIButton *exitFullScreenButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg3];
        
        UIImage *commentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment.png"];
        CGRect frameimg4 = CGRectMake(fullScreenViewFromVC.frame.size.width - 25 , 40, commentImage.size.width, commentImage.size.height);
        UIButton *commentButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg4];
        
        [exitFullScreenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(exitFullScreenPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
        [exitFullScreenButton setBackgroundImage:exitFullScreenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    
        [commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(diplayComments:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
        [commentButton setBackgroundImage:commentImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
        //[actionsView addSubview:flagButton];
        [fullScreenViewFromVC addSubview:cancelButton];
        [fullScreenViewFromVC addSubview:flagButton];
        [fullScreenViewFromVC addSubview:exitFullScreenButton];
        [fullScreenViewFromVC addSubview:commentButton];   
}
```

**Important note:**
`fullScreenViewFromVC` is an own class extending `UIView` and instantiated on my controller.
Basically I'm called the fullscreen method from a picture on a `UITableViewCell`
I'm using this `fullScreenViewFromVC` variable to store my data from the current selected cell to my controller.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code for how you're generating this interface; as it is, there isn't enough information to properly diagnose your problem

Comment: means only one `UIButton` not firing action ? and show your code

Comment: Aren't your buttons covered by the iOS status bar?

Comment: I've added my code but it's a basic one. Before calling this method I've done `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was because of another view that I had to hide. 
I thought that changing de `zPosition` of my view in fullscreen should be enough but it did not.

Problem solved.